# Is unset parameter in [[ compound command expected as empty string in bash?

Tags: bash

I am learning `[[` compound command, that is, new if sentence.

Some sites including [bashFAQ/31 on What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031), say that it does not need to quote parameter in it.
  My question is what exactly happened with unquoted unset parameter.
  I tried following code,

```
unset UNDEF_VAR
[[ ${UNDEF_VAR} = "" ]]
echo "result is $?"
```

and the output was

```
result is 0
```

So, I expect that unset variable, ${UNDEF_VAR}, between [[ ]] is translated as empty string on the contrary to the case of old if, "[".
 But unfortunately, I could not find the explicit explanation in sites above and bash manual. Some sites just says it is OK without the reason.
 Someone who knows the mechanism, please let me know. If I missed the explanation in sites/manual carelessly, please forgive me for using your time. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that checking for empty strings is normally done with `-z`.

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you, fedorqui. [[ -z ${UNDEF_VAR} ]] is a test of one variable case. [[ ${UNDEF_VAR} = "" ]] is a two variable case. I would like to know the exact mechanisms of both case.

Comment: In any context, an unset variable expands to an empty string. Most parameter expansion operators have two forms (`${var:-default}` vs. `${var-default}`, for example) to help you distinguish between an unset variable and a variable with a null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can find, the only reference to the expansion of an unset parameter is this sentence from the POSIX spec:

> The value, if any, of parameter shall be substituted.

A consequence of this is that `"$foo"` is an empty string because no value is placed between the quotes.

The `bash` man page has this to say about word-splitting:

> Explicit null arguments ("" or '')  are  retained.   Unquoted  implicit
>          null arguments, resulting from the expansion of parameters that have no
>          values, are removed.  If a parameter with no value is  expanded  within
>          double quotes, a null argument results and is retained.

Inside `[[ ... ]]`, a parameter expansion does not undergo word-splitting, so it is not clear *exactly* where "no value to substitute" becomes "null value". I assume that parameter expansions are treated as being *implicitly* quoted, whether or not they actually are.

Comment: thank you for telling it. I am impressed your broad and detailed knowledge and scientific logic. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The `[[` version behaves much more like you would expect it (at least as I would). It's independent if the variable is unset or empty.

```
$ unset foo
$ [[ $foo == "" ]] && echo true || echo false
true
$ foo=""
$ [[ $foo == "" ]] && echo true || echo false
true
```

With `[` you have to be careful. You need to quote it, if there's any chance that it might be empty or unset:

```
$ [ $foo = "" ] && echo true || echo false
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
false
$ [ "$foo" = "" ] && echo true || echo false
true
```

Also note that when you use `[[`, you should compare with `==`, and if you use `[`, compare with `=`. AFAIR `zsh` causes trouble, if you mix them.

And of course, as @fedorqui noted, comparing empty strings should be done with `-z`.

Comment: Thank you for telling me how they works in [[ and [. In [[ case, your instruction told me unquoted unset variable behaves like empty string. Have you ever see a reference or site which explicitly said, it is translated as an empty string? Or I should not care of it?